# Django aggregation--find each employee's total commissions

Tags: python, database, django, sum, aggregation

I am writing a django project and trying to find each employee's total commissions.

my sale model:

```
class Sale(models.Model):

commission=models.DecimalField(max_digits=7,decimal_places=2,blank=True,null=True)
ouremployee=models.ForeignKey(Employee,blank=True,null=True)
```

My sale object already recored commission associated with each sale and each employee but now I want to find each employee's total commission.

my employee model:

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    Name=models.CharField(max_length=30,blank=True,null=True)
Hire_date=models.DateTimeField(blank=True,null=True)
Salary=models.DecimalField(max_digits=8,decimal_places=1,blank=True,null=True)
Commission_rate=models.DecimalField(default=0,max_digits=3,decimal_places=3,blank=True,null=True)
Title=models.CharField(max_length=30,blank=True,null=True)
```

my views.py:

```
Sale = Sale.objects.all()
total_commission=0
TotalCommission = Sale.annotate(total_commission=Sum('ouremployee'))
```

My views.py doesnot work. May anyone help me .

Comment: A solved question should still be left as a question, and not edited -- that way other people can find it and take advantage of the knowledge imparted.

Comment: ...if you don't think a question is generic enough to be useful to other people, then it also shouldn't be on StackOverflow, and is a candidate to be closed and deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the relationship backwards:

```
Employee.objects.annotate(total_commission=Sum('sale__commission'))
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: dear alecxe. If I also want to sort commission within 7 days, how could I do. That is my code. Employee.objects.filter(str(datetime.datetime.now())-'sale__date') > str(datetime.timedelta(days=7))).annotate(total_commission=Sum('sale__commission'))